# Using a third party site for OAuth2 / OIDC authorization code flow- understanding the final steps

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I've a site which will hopefully use a third party service for logging in (through use of OAuth2 and OIDC). I understand 90% of the process involved but am failing to get what I see as the final step. I'll describe the steps as I see them here and maybe someone can help me fill in the gaps. In my set up the Resource Server and Authorisation servers are the same machine.

This is the login process as I envisage it.

1. User comes to my site (let's call it Site A) and clicks login
2. They're redirected to the authentication site (Site B) where they
   input their username / password.
3. Assuming correct credentials they're then redirected back to Site A with an auth code.
4. Site A takes this auth code and in a back channel communicates with Site B
   again asking to exchange the code for a token.
5. Site B provides an access token to Site A (not to the end user, to the server)
6. Site A then communicates with Site B again (Resource and Authentication servers are the same in this scenario) and gets the relevant user detail.

So the user is authenticated and we know what claims they have, however, what I don't get in the above scenario is how Site A knows who I (the end user) am.

I never logged in on Site A so presumably no cookie was set. Basically I've gone to the site, been redirected to another site, logged in there and then am redirected back to Site A but is there a cookie set at that last redirect to identify me?

I've read plenty about this online but haven't found a clear answer.

Also, am I correct in thinking that in authorization code flow that the access token never gets to the user but instead resides on the application server?

Comment: Do you need to log the user to SiteA also? Does SiteA already have existing users?

Comment: I need to log in to Site A by authenticating on Site B. Site A will have existing users but until they log in they can't access much of Site A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `really` want to know who the user is on SiteA, it has to be the user from SiteA's own user database. It makes sense if SiteA is not just a proxy for SiteB's API and has its own users, permissions and functionality.

To figure out who the user is on SiteA you will need to match all your SiteA's users with Auth Server's users.

Part 1. Import your existing users into Auth Server

If you control Auth Server, import all your current users into its user database. Every one of them will have Subject ID (Id on Auth Server side). Copy those IDs back to corresponding users in your SiteA's db: your SiteA's User table will have new column, for example:
userid, user_name, user_last_name, `user_auth_id` (new column)

if you can't import all your users, it gets complicated. The only way I can think of: you will have to log those users in twice - once into OIDC provider and once in SiteA and then associate SiteA's user with OIDC user.

Part 2. Matching the incoming user to the internal user in SiteA

In successful response from OIDC Server you will get ID Token back. It contains `sub` claim with Subject ID of the user. When you've got that, you will need to do a lookup in your internal DB and find a corresponding SiteA's user. If you did not find one, create a new user at SiteA (if all existing users had been imported)

Once you know who the user is, log them in to SiteA like you would normally do (give them a cookie for example).

Answer (score 1):

OpenID Connect auth servers provide the [userinfo endpoint](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo), which Site A can use for getting info about the user who authorized the access token (or the authorization code). For the auth provider (Site B) to be able to do it, it needs to keep association between a token and its user. So there is no cookie for this purpose.

You are correct about the auth code flow - the access token stays at the backend - there is no need to send it to the frontend / user.

To be able to pair the tokens kept at the SiteA backend with the consequent requests from the browser, you have few options:

- You can use a backend session with cookies, which is very easy, because most backend frameworks have a built-in support for it. The cookie is sent automatically with each request and the tokens can be stored in a session object. This solution may be harder to scale - if you need a cluster.
- You can create your own session implementation - either by using cookies or by some identifier expected on REST API as the Authorization HTTP header value. The backend session data can be kept in some distributed storage, such as Hazelcast or database. The session identifier can be in form of signed JWT, so you can keep user info in it.

Comment: Thanks but I'm still unclear when SiteA gets to associate me (the user using the browser) with the details I've just requested. I go to Site A initially, is there some cookie or something set at that stage? Otherwise how does Site A ever know to associate me (the end user) with the details it has just got back from Site B?

Comment: Ah, you mean how to pair the token kept by the backend with your consequent requests to the Site A (after being redirected from Site B)?

Comment: Exactly. I understand how the retrieval of info occurs and the authentication but I don't see how Site A after this process, then knows that the info it has on User21231 applies to me.

Comment: I updated the answer with info about how to maintain the session.